# Using Guzzle without cURL

Tags: stream, guzzle

I would like to use Guzzle to create POST requests, but I do not have cURL installed.

I use the following code:

```
$handler = new \GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler();

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => '...',
    'handler' => $handler
]);

$response = json_decode((string) $client->request(
    'POST',
    'api/ticket/' . $code,
    [
        'form_params' => [
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email
        ]
    ]
)->getBody());
```

However, this gives me an "Error creating resource: [message] fopen(...): failed to open stream" error message. I am not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to select the stream handler manually, Guzzle will do it automatically [if cURL is not available](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/functions.php#L103).

The error itself most likely means that you try to access a wrong URL. Please, check the resulting URL (base + one from the request).